# Bootstrap card image shows line, but not a stroke?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, border, card

Using the new version of Bootstrap and every card I have shows a line around the image. If I remove the image all together, there is a full line all the way around, if I add an image, there is a line usually on the top and bottom. I've removed the border, but not sure what is being called that keeps this line showing.

The issue can be seen here on these cards https://www.ididthat.ca/work.html

Any idea what this could be?